# What is the slope of the line tangent to $y = \sqrt{x}$ at $(16, 4)$?

Tags: calculus

I substituted into $\sqrt x$, but the program told me I was wrong. After trying to do it for 5 minutes I wondering whether it is a glitch, or if my answer is just wrong. [image]

Comment: Do you know the power rule for derivatives yet, or just the definition of derivative?

Comment: No I don't that actually is not part of this chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in your post, YES, you are correct: $$f(x) = \sqrt x = x^{1/2} \,\text{ and }\,a = 16$$
Try entering it again, in case you mistyped it the first time around. If it still is rejected by the program, then there is a glitch in the program.

That gives us $$\lim_{x\to 16}\frac{ \sqrt x - \sqrt{16}}{x- 16} = \lim_{x\to 16}\frac{\sqrt x - 4}{(\sqrt x - 4)(\sqrt x + 4)} = \cdots$$

Can you take it from here?